# EF Core 1.1 Check Constraint (Min, Max Notation)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many, check-constraints, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm trying to add a check constraint to a table via EF Core 1.1 using Code First.

The only answer I found was defining my constraint in the migration in a way like this:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Column CHECK (Column >= X);");
```

My ER-Modell looks like this:

Min-Max Relationship
[image: Min-Max Relationship]

In my picture you can see that a "Process" has minimum 2 "Processelements".

I would like to know if there is another way to add a CHECK Constraint which checks if there are minimum 2 "Processelements" in this relationship. Maybe a solution with fluent-api or data annotations?

Comment: You can't constrain a relationship to have a minimum number of children. Imagine how that would work in the database. You have to insert a new `Process` row before the `Processelements` so it would immediately fail.

Comment: Yes, you're right @DavidG. My ER-Modell is a theoretical approach which wouldn't work in practice. So this means I have to change the relationship from [2,many] to [0,many] and I could check via a method if the 'Process' has minimum two 'Processelements'. Am I right?